# 'd3.nest()' cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use very simple `d3.nest()` functionality but get failed with the error 'Cannot read property of undefined' related to one of the data columns.

First I tried to process the stand alone txt file and got stuck. Second I tried to process a simple variable created inside the code and didn't succeeded.

I understand that the problem I'm posting could have been discussed not once. But I searched and didn't find any responses just for my case. Think I'm doing incorrectly something that is peculiar for a hole newbie only.

Here's the code:

```
const db = [
        {
            'net': '36,6',
            'lon': '30',
            'lat': '50'
        },
        {
            'net': 'erka',
            'lon': '40',
            'lat': '55'
        },
        {
            'net': 'erka',
            'lon': '40',
            'lat': '70'
        }
        ];

    console.log(db); //output looks fine with all three columns needed 

    const nest = d3.nest(db)
        .key(function(d) {return d.net;}) //triggers the error
        .entries(function(d) {return d.lon;});
```

The error is:

> Cannot read property 'net' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

The `nest()` method doesn't ask for any argument. Therefore, this...

```
d3.nest(db)
//-------^
```

... has no effect. Instead of that, you have to pass your data array to `entries`. Have a look:

```js
const db = [{
    'net': '36,6',
    'lon': '30',
    'lat': '50'
  },
  {
    'net': 'erka',
    'lon': '40',
    'lat': '55'
  },
  {
    'net': 'erka',
    'lon': '40',
    'lat': '70'
  }
];

const nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.net;
  })
  .entries(db);

console.log(nest)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It's not clear to me why you're passing that anonymous function to `entries`. I'd say that you probably want another `key`.

Comment: `why you're passing that anonymous function` I just told that I know that I make something wrong - I didn't get that `entries` should (or could?) be all the data, I tried to insert a selectable field as a grouped data))) Many thanks!